# When is a time series considered to be "complex"? (not complex-valued)

Tags: time-series

what is a measure or definition for **complex time series**. When is a time series considered to be normal and when it is considered to be a complex?

A lot of researcher saying they predicting/analayzing complex time series. However, I am asking me what is the property that makes a time series a complex one.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the times one refers to a complex time-series to indicate that this is not, for example, a **predictable** periodic time-series or a sequence of **repeating** patterns with **fixed** seasonality.

Complex time-series would be those coming e.g. from **real-world** measurements, and can be **non-stationary**, very **noisy**, have **different** and **dynamic** behaviors and seasonality, contain **outliers** and **missing** values, and so on.